# When I try to show an uploaded image html shows me another one but if I refresh the page it shows me the right one

Tags: php, html, image, ftp, uploading

I made a page for an e-commerce website where if you want to add images you select them and you upload everything to the server. The problem is (like I mentioned on the title) that he shows me images uploaded before and when I refresh the page it displays the right one. I alredy tried to make a location.reload() with javascript but I don't like the fact that he has to load the page twice. Also I noticed that on mobile phones and on tablet (connected at the same wi-fi of my pc) it takes a lot of time to upload images.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
  <div id="ctn1">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="aggiungi_immagini.php">
      <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
        <span>Seleziona Immagini</span>
        <input id="uploadBtn" class="upload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
      </div>
      <input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Nessun File selezionato" disabled="disabled" /><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Carica" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form><br>
    <?php
    $files = array();
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator('images/'.$_SESSION['prodid'].'/') as $fileInfo) {
        if($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
        $files[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
    }
    foreach ($files as $filename) {

    ?>
      <style>
        #imagelisticon{
          color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
          position: absolute;
          margin-left:-100px;
          z-index: 2;
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          line-height: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          width:200px;
          font-size: 40px;
        }
        #imgcnt{
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          position:relative;
          margin-top:40px;
          width:200px;
          height:200px;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 1px solid lightgrey;
          line-height: 198px;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        .trash{
          position: absolute;
          vertical-align: text-top;
          margin-top: 5px;
          margin-left: 50px;
          z-index:3;
        }
      </style>
        <div id="imgcnt" style="background-image: url('images/<?php echo $id;?>/<?php echo $filename;?>');">
          <div id="<?php echo $filename;?>" class="btn btn-danger trash"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <i id="imagelisticon" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?></div><br>
      <center><a href="modifica_prodotto.php"><div class="btn btn-success">
      Conferma
    </div></a></center><?php
    $valid_formats = array("gif","jpg","jpeg","png","wbmp","bmp","webp","xbm","xpm");
    $max_file_size = 80*1024^2; //10 MB
    $path = "images/".$_SESSION['prodid']."/"; // Upload directory
    $count = 1;
    $picid=$id;
    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        // Ripeto per ogni file caricato
      ?><div id="ctnmultiimages" style="heigth:300px;"><?php
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
                continue; // Salto se ci sono stati errori
            }
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {
                if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                    $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                    continue; // Salto per i formati troppo grandi
                }
                elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                    $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                    continue; // Salto per i formati non validi
                }
                else{ // Nessun errore, sposta i file
                $kaboom = explode(".", $name); // Split file name into an array using the dot
                $fileExt = end($kaboom);
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], "images/".$id."/".$name)){
                $count++;
            }
            }
        }

    }?>

        <?php
    }


?>


</body>
</html>
<script>
document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {
  document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};
$("DIV[class='btn btn-danger trash']").click(function(){
    var delfile = ($(this).attr("id"))
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'delete.php',
        data: {
            source1: delfile
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
})

</script>
```

Sorry if the code is long and not well-indentated but I screwed up to fit it in the code format :)

By the way I know the code is a little long so I'll show you the part where I echo the pics:

```
<?php
$files = array();
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('images/'.$_SESSION['prodid'].'/') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
    $files[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
}
foreach ($files as $filename) {

?>
    <div id="imgcnt" style="background-image: url('images/<?php echo $id;?>/<?php echo $filename;?>');">
      <div id="<?php echo $filename;?>" class="btn btn-danger trash"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <i id="imagelisticon" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

P.S. I removed the style part so you can see the back-end.

I store my images in the directory 'images' and then in a directory that has the name of the id of the product I want to link images. So if I want to store images for the product that has id=25, images will be in this path: "images/25/"

Thanks for helping me, I relly need to find a method to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't show your uploaded images immediately because the code responsible for uploading is after displaying images. That means you first display images in your directory then uploading new images to this directory. The thing you want is you first upload and then display images, so move your upload code at the beginning of the file or simply above your first foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks man! Do you know why it takes so long to upload images from mobile?

Comment: It's hard to say. The only thing I can think of is the distance between you and your Wi-Fi router. If you're far away, the signal could be too weak and it can result in slow uploading. If that's not the case and your mobile is located close to the router while uploading - I've no idea.